# Javascript game collision detection wall

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I've been following W3schools tutorial on creating a JavaScript game in a canvas https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_obstacles.asp

I've got to the stage where they add an obstacle in. Currently, it has collision detection which stops the game when it hits the wall. I am trying to figure out a way to treat it like a wall where the box could hit it and no longer move that direction and continue the game, making the wall work.

I've previously tried detecting what direction hit the wall and stopping movement that direction, but when I hold down an arrow key it moves through it.

Heres what I've got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/j9cy1mne/1/

```
<body onload="startGame()">
  <script>
    var myGamePiece;
    var myObstacle;

    var speed = 3;

    function startGame() {
      myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
      myObstacle = new component(10, 200, "green", 300, 120);
      myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
      canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
      start: function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
      },
      clear: function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      },
      stop: function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.speedX = 0;
      this.speedY = 0;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }
      this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;

        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
          crash = false;

        }


        return crash;
      }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
      if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
        console.log("crash");
      } else {
        myGameArea.clear();
        myObstacle.update();
        myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
        myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
        myGamePiece.update();
      }
    }
    document.onkeydown = checkKeyD;

    function checkKeyD(e) {

      e = e || window.event;

      if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        // up arrow
        myGamePiece.speedY = -speed;
      } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
        myGamePiece.speedY = speed;
      } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        // left arrow
        myGamePiece.speedX = -speed;
      } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right arrow
        myGamePiece.speedX = speed;
      }

    }

    document.onkeyup = clearmove;

    function clearmove() {
      myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
      myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
    }

  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    console.log("crash");
  } else {
```

In a real physics engine you detect collisions then you resolve collisions. The simplest "resolve collision" would be to move the piece back to the place it was before the crash. Something like:

```
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    resolveCollision(myGamePiece, myObstacle);
  } else {
```

But to do this you'll need to modify your physics engine, and your movement function to use a velocity vector. That means that instead of `function checkKeyD(e)` moving the piece, that function sets a velocity vector.  Then `crashWith()` will determine if the position plus the velocity vector is going to crash and resolve collision will un-crash it.